# Not able to access Raspberry Pi from outside network

Tags: port-forwarding, dynamic-dns, ddns

I have set up a webserver on a Raspberry Pi, and it is working on perfectly on the LAN. I have assigned this machine a static IP address as well. It is currently running at `192.168.0.111:80`.

I have configured port forwarding on my D-Link router like this:

```
Name: HTTP
Public port: 80~80
IP Address: 192.168.0.111
Private Port: 80~80
```

I have not yet been able to successfully access the machine from outside the network. I keep getting network timeouts on port `80` (and few other ports which I have tried, like `4000`).

I am setting up a dynamic DNS solution so that I can SSH into the machine from outside and run a webserver on this machine as well.

I am trying to use No-IP and DynDNS for this purpose.

Comment: Many ISP's block servers running on residential networks...

Comment: @DavidPostill how do I test if my ISP is blocking it. Any possible workarounds to it ?

Comment: I guess I can use `ngrok` to access the webserver from outside the network. But not sure how will I `ssh` into the machine.

Comment: I suppose you know that you have to use the Public IP and that the device from which you try to connect has to be (very probable) on an external network as often routers don't connect to services on the public IP from within the local network. I sometimes use public port scanners to check if my port is open (eg. Shields UP! by GRC). If it will not be shown to be allowed, then it could be that your service is listening only on your local network - check ALL firewalls.

Comment: @abhishek77in you could try phoning them and asking...

Comment: Thanks, look like it's an ISP issue. Using `ngrok` I can remotely ssh and run my webserver, so that worked for me.